# Creating a replace segue to a detail view on iPad split screen programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I've got the iPhone working fine with creating a segue programmatically.
e.g.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" 
                                                         bundle:nil];
FooBarViewController *foobarViewController = (FooBarViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"foobarViewControllerID”];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:foobarViewController animated:YES];
```

Now I'm trying to do something similar on the iPad storyboard.
The goal being to programmatically change the detail view to a view on the storyboard.
I thought maybe:

```
[self.splitViewController.navigationController presentViewController:foorbarViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

However this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've solved my own question with the following function:

```
- (void) presentDetailView : (UIViewController *) viewcontroller {
    UINavigationController *detailNavCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller];
    detailNavCtrl.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    detailNavCtrl.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    [[[self.splitViewController viewControllers] lastObject] presentViewController:detailNavCtrl animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```